# How can I obtain/process polygon data regarding roads from Open Street Maps

Tags: rendering, polygon, openstreetmap

I've been looking through Open Street Map's and for general interest I wanted to be able to use a programming language e.g. python to render the streets graphically. Not by using map tiles, but by analysing the data and drawing my own polygons/lines.

I've obtained a OSM Shapefile(The shapefile is a common standard for representing geospatial vector data.) and I've converted it to a JSON file to make it readable for my own understanding.

When the shapefile is imported into QGIS it will fully represent the street system as it was on OSM. But when I look through the JSON file, there are coordinates, but not enough data to build polygons of streets.

A single street looks like this:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[151.1734844,-32.5675228],[151.1735678,-32.5670849],[151.173932,-32.5671361]]},"properties":{"osm_id":"559250924","bridge":"","highway":"service","layer":"","name":"Maple Lane","oneway":"","smoothness":"","surface":"","tunnel":"","width":"","z_index":"3"}},
```

Each street will contain a different number of coordinates. But as I stated before there is not enough to go off to construct a street layout.

How do I find the data in a shapefile to construct my own street layout? It should be there, as QGIS is achieving this with the files I uploaded.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "ploygons of streets"?  Do you mean the whole street area, from one side of the road to the other, as opposed to just a line representation of a road from A to B?

Comment: Esentially I just want the data to construct a line representation of the streets.

Comment: Shapefiles are already pre-processed data, it's not the native OSM data format! Better use OSM XML format instead.

Comment: How do you convert the shape file to GeoJSON? Why you do not originally obtain OSM XML as suggested by mmd? By the way looking the GeoJSON feature at http://geojson.io/#map=18/-32.56710/151.17385 looks fine to me.